# Why is WKWebView not opening links with target="_blank"?

Tags: ios, wkwebview

`WKWebView` does not open any links which have `target="_blank"` a.k.a. 'Open in new Window' attribute in their HTML `<a href>`-Tag.

Comment: please update the correct answer marked

Answer (score 256, accepted):

My solution is to cancel the navigation and load the request with loadRequest: again. This will be come the similar behavior like UIWebView which always open new window in the current frame.

Implement the `WKUIDelegate` delegate and set it to `_webview.uiDelegate`. Then implement:

```
- (WKWebView *)webView:(WKWebView *)webView createWebViewWithConfiguration:(WKWebViewConfiguration *)configuration forNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction windowFeatures:(WKWindowFeatures *)windowFeatures
{
  if (!navigationAction.targetFrame.isMainFrame) {
    [webView loadRequest:navigationAction.request];
  }

  return nil;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. We tried the accepted answer with no success. But @Cloud's answer works, and [this response on the dev forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1059229#1059229) explains why.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Don't forget to set the `UIDelegate` property, since this methods is declared in `WKUIDelegate` not `WKNavigationDelegate`.

Comment: Ok, I see that people wanna use the WKWebView like this. I implemented the possibility to open target=_blank-Links in the same WKWebView (as shown above) in my project https://github.com/sticksen/STKWebKitViewController.

Comment: @ChristopherPickslay But how do you open links that should be opened in an other applications? Appstore links? There is an issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29056854/how-can-i-understand-if-uiapplication-is-going-to-open-link-in-safari-app

Comment: @BergP we parse the link. If the host contains `itunes.apple.com`, we call `openURL:`. Otherwise, if the scheme starts with `http`, we do the above. Finally if it's not an app store link or http url, we call `openURL:`. Incidentally, we also show a prompt before calling `openURL:`, giving the user the option to ignore it, as lots of sites and ads are now doing auto-redirects to their app or the App Store.

Comment: @ChristopherPickslay when using this method with my WKWebView the request url is always blank, so the webview directs to a blank white page, any ideas?

Comment: @Cloud can we get this in Swift?

Comment: @JasonMurray Refer to my stack overflow [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955880/wkwebview-not-opening-some-target-blank-links) regarding this issue and how I resolved it . HTH

Comment: When the '_blank' request is sent from a form with post data, I find the post data will be lost!!!  Any help?  @Cloud Wu

Comment: Having the same issue with @JasonMurray. Rolled back to UIWebView with the custom shitty swipe back gesture.

Answer (score 104):

The answer from @Cloud Xu is the correct answer. Just for reference, here it is in Swift:

```
// this handles target=_blank links by opening them in the same view
func webView(webView: WKWebView!, createWebViewWithConfiguration configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration!, forNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction!, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures!) -> WKWebView! {
    if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
        webView.load(navigationAction.request)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: how would you write it if you wanted it to open in Safari instead? Also what do I need to reference in the view controller to get this to work?

Comment: To get the new page to open in mobile safari, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30604481/558789

Comment: This works for links, but doesn't seem to detect new windows opened with JavaScript, i.e., window.open(url, "_blank")

Comment: FYI webView.loadRequest has apparently been renamed webView.load in recent versions of the API

Answer (score 77):

To use latest version of Swift 4.2+

```
import WebKit
```

Extend your class with **WKUIDelegate**

Set delegate for webview

```
self.webView.uiDelegate = self
```

Implement protocol method

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
    if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
        webView.load(navigationAction.request)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Not a real duplicate. There are differences in the optionality of the parameters that do not conform to the Swift 4.1 WKUIDelegate protocol in the answer you linked to.

Comment: Hi,
When I'm loading WKWebview with Pinterest URL, I was unable to open "Continue with Facebook". Now I can able to click and get the information on "Continuew with Google". Help me out please.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with wkwebview ; login and redirect not worked in my app. Any Help ?

Comment: please anyone can help me out, I have assigned delegate uiDelegate to wkwebview but its method create web view with configuration is not being called

Answer (score 32):

Add yourself as the *WKNavigationDelegate*

```
_webView.navigationDelegate = self;
```

and implement following code in the delegate callback *decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:*

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler
{
    //this is a 'new window action' (aka target="_blank") > open this URL externally. If we´re doing nothing here, WKWebView will also just do nothing. Maybe this will change in a later stage of the iOS 8 Beta
    if (!navigationAction.targetFrame) { 
        NSURL *url = navigationAction.request.URL;
        UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        if ([app canOpenURL:url]) {
            [app openURL:url];
        }
    }
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
}
```

P.S.: This code is from my little project [`STKWebKitViewController`](https://github.com/sticksen/STKWebKitViewController), which wraps a usable UI around WKWebView.

Comment: There's a typo. A dot is missing between WKNavigationActionPolicy and Allow

Comment: @stk How can I understand if UIApplication is going to open link in Safari app? If it is Appstore link - I need to open ot in the Appstore app, but if it is usual web page - I need to open it in the same WKWebView http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29056854/how-can-i-understand-if-uiapplication-is-going-to-open-link-in-safari-app

Comment: @LeoKoppelkamm It's not a typo rather it's Objective-C not Swift. ;)

Comment: @Crashalot Did you find the solution for window.open ?

Comment: @Sam Have you checked this answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190234/wkwebview-and-window-open

Comment: This is the correct answer - Cloud's answer above is using a method deprecated since ios9

Answer (score 21):

If you've already set the WKWebView.navigationDelegate

**WKWebView.navigationDelegate = self;**

you just need to implement:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler
{
    BOOL shouldLoad = [self shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationAction.request]; // check the url if necessary

    if (shouldLoad && navigationAction.targetFrame == nil) {
        // WKWebView ignores links that open in new window
        [webView loadRequest:navigationAction.request];
    }

    // always pass a policy to the decisionHandler
    decisionHandler(shouldLoad ? WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow : WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel);
}
```

this way you don't need to implement the WKUIDelegate method.

Comment: This works for links, but doesn't seem to detect new windows opened with JavaScript, i.e., window.open(url, "_blank")

Comment: @Crashalot Have you checked this answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190234/wkwebview-and-window-open

Comment: Thank you. In nativescript "webView" "CreateWebViewWith" is not called, and I dont know why but  instead decidePolicyForNavigationAction works.

Answer (score 19):

`Cloud xu`'s answer solves my issue.

In case someone need the equivalent Swift(4.x/5.0) version, here is it:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
    if let frame = navigationAction.targetFrame,
        frame.isMainFrame {
        return nil
    }
    // for _blank target or non-mainFrame target
    webView.load(navigationAction.request)
    return nil
}
```

Of course you have to set `webView.uiDelegate` firstly.

Answer (score 8):

None of those solutions worked for me, I did solve the issue by :

1) Implementing WKUIDelegate

```
@interface ViewController () <WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate>
```

2) Setting the UIDelegate delegate of the wkWebview

```
self.wkWebview.UIDelegate = self;
```

3) Implementing the **createWebViewWithConfiguration** method

```
- (WKWebView *)webView:(WKWebView *)webView createWebViewWithConfiguration:(WKWebViewConfiguration *)configuration forNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction windowFeatures:(WKWindowFeatures *)windowFeatures {

if (!navigationAction.targetFrame.isMainFrame) {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[navigationAction.request URL]];
}
return nil;  }
```

Comment: I just get a SIGABRT when doing this. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

I confirm that Bill Weinman's Swift code is correct. But need to mention that you also need to delegate UIDelegate for it to work, in case you are new to iOS developing like me.

Something like this:

```
self.webView?.UIDelegate = self
```

So there's three places that you need to make changes.

Comment: Type in your code, it's: `self.webView.UIDelegate = self`

Comment: Not sure if it's implied, but in order for this line of code to work in iOS 10 you `ViewController` needs to inherit `WKUIDelegate`.
i.e. `class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler, WKUIDelegate`

Answer (score 5):

You can also push another view controller, or open a new tab, etc:

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWithConfiguration configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, forNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
    var wv: WKWebView?

    if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
        if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController")  as? ViewController {
            vc.url = navigationAction.request.URL
            vc.webConfig = configuration
            wv = vc.view as? WKWebView

            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }

    return wv
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to set `vc.url`? I'm not setting it, and the web view is being loaded properly. Also, in my experience I am only seeing `createWebViewWithConfiguration` called when `navigationAction.targetFrame` is `nil`. Can you describe a scenario where this wouldn't be true?

Comment: @MasonG.Zhwiti I was actively using WKWebViews for a project last fall, but since then haven't done anything with them - so I really cannot answer your question. At the time I posted the above it did work. I cannot fathom how it works without setting the vc.url though.

Comment: I think it works without because you're returning the web view you created, and then (I'm guessing) whatever asked you to create it takes care of using the web view to load the URL in question.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [allen huang answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46519122/4488252)

### Details

- Xcode Version 10.3 (10G8), Swift 5

### Targets

- detect links with `target=“_blank”`
- `push` view controller with webView if current controller has `navigationController`
- `present` view controller with webView in all other cases

### Solution

```
webView.uiDelegate = self

// .....

extension ViewController: WKUIDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
        guard   navigationAction.targetFrame == nil,
                let url =  navigationAction.request.url else { return nil }
        let vc = ViewController(url: url, configuration: configuration)
        if let navigationController = navigationController {
            navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
            return vc.webView
        }
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return nil
    }
}
```

### Full sample

> Info.plist

add in your Info.plist transport security setting

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

> ViewController

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var url = URL(string: "https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_links_target")!
    private weak var webView: WKWebView!

    init (url: URL, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.url = url
        navigationItem.title = ""
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { super.init(coder: aDecoder) }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        initWebView()
        webView.loadPage(address: url)
    }

    private func initWebView() {
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
        view.addSubview(webView)
        self.webView = webView
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}

extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        guard let host = webView.url?.host else { return }
        navigationItem.title = host
    }
}

extension ViewController: WKUIDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
        guard   navigationAction.targetFrame == nil,
                let url =  navigationAction.request.url else { return nil }
        let vc = ViewController(url: url, configuration: configuration)
        if let navigationController = navigationController {
            navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
            return vc.webView
        }
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return nil
    }
}

extension WKWebView {
    func loadPage(address url: URL) { load(URLRequest(url: url)) }
    func loadPage(address urlString: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        loadPage(address: url)
    }
}
```

### Storyboards

**Version 1**

[image]

**Version 2**

[image]

Comment: hi , after login with facebook , how to open share window for  facebook share in similar way ? I have logged in with creating new wkwebview , now user is logged in. Now how to track share window ?

Comment: Thank you, your solution save my life :)

Answer (score 4):

To open _blank pages in Mobile Safari and if you use Swift:

```
webView.navigationDelegate = self
```

And implement this in the WKNavigationDelegate:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil, let url = navigationAction.request.url {
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.allow)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
-(WKWebView *)webView:(WKWebView *)webView createWebViewWithConfiguration:(WKWebViewConfiguration *)configuration forNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction windowFeatures:(WKWindowFeatures *)windowFeatures {

if (!navigationAction.targetFrame.isMainFrame) {


    WKWebView *newWebview = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:configuration];
    newWebview.UIDelegate = self;
    newWebview.navigationDelegate = self;
    [newWebview loadRequest:navigationAction.request];
    self.view = newWebview;

    return  newWebview;
}

return nil;
}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {

    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
}

- (void)webViewDidClose:(WKWebView *)webView {
    self.view = self.webView;
}
```

As you can see, what we do here is just opening a new `webView`with the new url and controlling the posibility of being closed, just if you need a response from that `second webview`to be displayed on the first.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered some issues that can not be resolved by just using `webView.load(navigationAction.request)`. So I use create a new webView to do and it just works fine.

```swift
//MARK:- WKUIDelegate
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
    NSLog(#function)

    if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
        NSLog("=> Create a new webView")

        let webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds, configuration: configuration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self

        self.webView = webView

        return webView
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
**Use following function to create web view**
 
func initWebView(configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration) 
{
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds, configuration: configuration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view.addSubview(webView)
        self.webView = webView
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 if webView == nil { initWebView(configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration()) }
   webView?.load(url: url1)
}

**WKUIDelegate Method need to be implemented**

extension WebViewController: WKUIDelegate {

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
        // push new screen to the navigation controller when need to open url in another "tab"
        print("url:\(String(describing: navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString))")
        if let url = navigationAction.request.url, navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
            let viewController = WebViewController()
            viewController.initWebView(configuration: configuration)
            viewController.url1 = url
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
            }
            return viewController.webView
        }
        
        return nil
    }
}

extension WKWebView 

{
    func load(url: URL) { load(URLRequest(url: url)) }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this method to download pdf in web view

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView?