# How to open WKWebView target='_blank' links externally (OS X)?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webkit, wkwebview

I'm trying to have a `WKWebView` in my Mac app (Objective-C) open links with `_target='_blank'` externally in the default web browser (i.e. using `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:aURL]`).

I've read two similar questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713069/why-is-wkwebview-not-opening-links-with-target-blank), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955880/wkwebview-not-opening-some-target-blank-links)) but the solutions found do not work for me on OS X. For 1, `webView:createWebViewWithConfiguration:forNavigationAction:windowFeatures` gives a nil request URL; and 2 does not work for some pages with dynamic content (e.g. [Inbox by Google / inbox.google.com](https://inbox.google.com)).

Are there any good or unorthodox/hack-y solutions to the problem for OS X? Seeing as `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` provides a `nil` URL for the `navigationAction`'s `request.URL`, is there another way of getting clicked links to open them in the user's browser?