# WKWebView and window.open

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

It appears that a lot of links on websites use window.open in their onclick handlers but WKWebView seems to completely ignore window.open.

Is there a workaround for this?

I tried setting javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically preference to true but that didn't seem to help

Answer (score 52, accepted):

When a web application calls `window.open()` in JavaScript, the `WKWebView` will call the 
`- webView:createWebViewWithConfiguration:forNavigationAction:windowFeatures:`
 method on its `UIDelegate`.

In that delegate method you should create a new `WKWebView` with the `WKWebViewConfiguration` that is given to you. If you present this new `WKWebView` on screen, it will load with the correct content.

This is documented in the [WKUIDelegate documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKUIDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/WKUIDelegate/webView:createWebViewWithConfiguration:forNavigationAction:windowFeatures:), although it is not very explicit that this is called as a result of `window.open()`.

Comment: Could you add information on how to do this with JavaScript? I'm using Cordova! : D

Comment: It is obvious but you will need to delegate your `webView.uiDelegate` in order to implement this `createWebViewWith configuration`.

You will need this if you migrated from `UIWebView` to `WKWebView` as the `window.open` won't work.

Comment: Hello @Stefan, what possibly could be the issue for the method `createWebViewWithConfiguration` not being trigger? Despite delegate has been set to my webview? Appreciate if you could drop your 2 cents. Details question posted here.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60851538/wkwebview-does-not-trigger-method-createwebviewwithconfiguration

Comment: For anyone that missed it, you need to set  `web.configuration.preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true` (defaults to false in iOS)