# WKWebView does not trigger method createWebViewWithConfiguration

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview, wkuidelegate

I'm trying to run Javascript within  in a HTML Source. The code inside is suppose to open a new window with another HTML Source I given. What's my mistake here?

(**My goal** is to prove the WKWebView has ability in opening nested popup window) Meaning that, Webview opened a *PopUpWindow A*, then PopUpWindow A will `window.open()` *PopUpWindow B*, then PopUpWindow B will `window.open()` *PopUpWindow C*.

In my WKWebView I have done the following:

1. Implemented `WKUIDelegate`
2. Set `_webView.UIDelegate = self;`
3. Set both the preferences:
   `wkWebViewConfig.preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = YES;
     wkWebViewConfig.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = YES;`
4. Create method below

```
- (WKWebView *)webView:(WKWebView *)webView createWebViewWithConfiguration:(WKWebViewConfiguration *)configuration forNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction windowFeatures:(WKWindowFeatures *)windowFeatures
{
  if (!navigationAction.targetFrame.isMainFrame) {
    [webView loadRequest:navigationAction.request];
  }
  return nil;
}
```

**My sample html source as follow:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <script language="javascript">
      function init()
      { 
          setTimeout( () => {
            window.open("testing2.html","mywindow","toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,width=910,height=750");
          }, 3000)
          document.redirectForm.target="mywindow";
          document.redirectForm.submit();
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Going to testing2
    <form>
         <input type="button" onclick="init()" value="Click" />
      </form>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        init();
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried replacing `"testing2.html"` with `https://www.google.com`, it does show up Google website. But again, my goal here is to ensure my WKWebView is able to open **Nested PopUp Window** due to some architecture design of some client API

Some similar ques and ans I've read:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33198751/4311268
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39073499/4311268
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25853806/4311268

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the reason is because `window.open` does not open local file (eg, testing.html). Hence I have installed `http-server` to host my files on localhost.

1. npm i http-server -g
2. cd to my folder where all the html file placed
3. run `http-server`
4. Run the last IP address:8080 return from `http-server`
5. You will see all your .html files there in localhost
6. Replace your .html file with **localhost link**