# Links opening in new window or tab is not loaded in native iOS

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView in my application, there are some buttons inside the WKWebView on clicking on it, a new page is not loaded. By the look of it, they are trying to open an about_blank page. In the browser, the link is opening in a new page and the URL is loaded.

Answer (score 9):

The way that you do this is by implementing `WKUIDelegate` and override this method

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView?
```

If you return a new `WKWebView` with the passed configuration, the request will be loaded to a new webview. Since `target=_blank` tries to open a new window in browser, this method compensates for that in iOS. You could launch a new `UIViewController` with this new `WKWebView` where the request for `target=_blank` page.

Here is a simple example, where I substitute the main `WKWebView` with new webView, and load the request in same viewcontroller,

```
extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate {

    public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
        let newWebView = WKWebView(frame: self.webView.frame,
                         configuration: configuration)
        view.addSubview(newWebView)
        return newWebView
    }
}
```

This in someway works like a tab in browser. But, bear in mind that with the change as above, forward and backward do not work, since you have created a new webview. If you want everything to work, I suggest that you load a new viewcontroller with this webview or create a new view where this would be loaded and shown, and you could switch to other main webview.

Comment: Also, this is useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713069/why-is-wkwebview-not-opening-links-with-target-blank

Answer (score 6):

I went with this approach, even though this approach opens the URL in a device safari browser, anyway those links are pointing to external links, this method helped

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
    if let url = navigationAction.request.url {
        let app = UIApplication.shared
        if app.canOpenURL(url) {
            app.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
}
decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift Solution

```
public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
        
        if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
            self.webView.load(navigationAction.request)
            }
        return nil
    }
```

You need to delegate WKUIDelegate

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @BXV and @Ucdemir

Actually I don't want to open in an external browser or tab, so below is my solution to open in the same web page.

I only removed from @BXV answer:

```
app.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

And picked the line from @Ucdemir answer:

```
self.webView.load(navigationAction.request)
```

So final code is:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
            if let url = navigationAction.request.url {
                let app = UIApplication.shared
                if app.canOpenURL(url) {
                    //app.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                    self.webView.load(navigationAction.request)
                }
            }
        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
```

Answer for those who are still facing the issue or want to do the same.