# iOS WKWebKit in External Link Click not working

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

WKWebView in loading this link:- https://moc.e2logy.com/about-us/divisions/foreign-trade-territorial-division/foreign-trade-nafta/

When I am click on below link
https://tradestat.commerce.gov.in/eidb/default.asp

Giving error
Unknown result for URL 0x600000841f80 (https)
https://tradestat.commerce.gov.in/eidb/default.asp

Comment: Can you include the code for what you've tried so far please?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can check:

1. Verify that the `<a href` links doesn't contain `target="_blank"`
   attribute since WKWebView doesn't know how to open the link in a new
   tab. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25853806/810466 for how to work
   around that.
2. Check if the link is HTTPS or update the `App Transport Security Settings` with the `Allow Arbitrary` Loads option
3. Make sure that you start the loading request only after adding the
   WKWebView to the view hierarchy in `didMoveToParentViewController:`
   since it may make javascript to fail if it tries to run outside the
   view hierarchy
4. Implement the WKWebView NavigationDelegate methods and make sure you
   return `WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow` when deciding the policy for
   the request

Answer (score 0):

I got issue. issue of access of class of javascript message

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
             completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: message, attributes: [
        NSAttributedString.Key.font : Utility.getFont(fontName: FONT.RobotoRegular, sizeOfFont: FONT_SIZE.FOURTEEN),
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.black
    ])

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.setValue(attributedString, forKey: "attributedMessage")
    alertController.view.tintColor = UIColor.black

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: LocalizationSystem.sharedInstance.localizedStringForKey(key: "ok", comment: "").uppercased(), style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        self.isExternal = 1
        completionHandler(true)
    }))

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: LocalizationSystem.sharedInstance.localizedStringForKey(key: "cancel", comment: "").uppercased(), style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        self.isExternal = 0
        completionHandler(false)
    }))

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
}
```

when I am using this method getting success

Thanks