# iOS swift WKWebView Problem with PayPal Smart Button Popup with navigationAction.request being empty

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, wkwebview

When i click on the PayPal Smart Button Checkout the website tries to open a PopUp. But with our common solution for empty target frames like new tabs it only shows a blank page. **Strangely in the case of this PayPal button the navigationAction.request is empty**. So the normal solution doesn't work.

In our WKWebView we have this code that is working fine for every popup and new tab that we had in the past:

```
extension WebShopViewController: WKUIDelegate {

public func webView(
    _ webView: WKWebView,
    createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration,
    for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction,
    windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures
    ) -> WKWebView? {
        if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
            webView.load(navigationAction.request)
        }
    return nil
}
```

The solution comes from here: [Why is WKWebView not opening links with target="_blank"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713069/why-is-wkwebview-not-opening-links-with-target-blank)

The Paypal Button can be found here:
https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Do you know a solution that would work for the paypal button and also for new links?

Answer (score 0):

The PayPal Checkout [does not support webviews](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/reference/info-security-guidelines/#secure-applications). Use a Safari View Controller.

If the buttons are being shown in a webview, use a library like [popup-bridge-ios](https://github.com/braintree/popup-bridge-ios)

Comment: If you don't intercept the request it works. Safari View Controller is no option. The popup bridge is a nice suggestion but doesn't work with the smart button since you can't inject there. Only solution i see right now is to check if the url and disable the code if its paypal. Then everyhing works. But i would like a better solution. Maybe there is none tho.

Comment: SVC or similar browsers with a full address bar are the only thing supported by PayPal, as far as I know. The popup bridge is designed to work with the smart buttons, but needs to be pre-loaded natively.